# automatically calculate menu item widths with css

Tags: html, css

I have a menu created with ul li's. I want to automatically position menu items with css, so that after changing menu item text, the position will be recalculated. In the example fiddle positioning is done with padding and in this case if text becomes longer it will go to next line.

example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/9WbaC/

Comment: What is different in your fiddle than what you want to do? Is there something not working in the fiddle? Is text going to the next line undesirable?

Comment: in the fiddle positioning is done using padding and if text gets longer the menu item will move to next line. I need it to be dynamically positioned for the items to get closer to each other if one of them becomes longer

Comment: Are you using PHP (or some other language) for your website? What you're trying to do is not possible by just using html and css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem I always have, because our site's navigation are always built by the client and we have no clue how many items there will be.

You can sort of do this with the `table` type display properties:

```
nav {display:table;}
nav ul {display:table-row;}
nav ul li {display:table-cell;}
```

In addition to this, I removed `float` from your list items:

- Here's what it looks like with lots of items: http://jsfiddle.net/9WbaC/2/

I used text with white space, so you could see the effect this will have on wrapping.

- Here's what it looks like with only a few items: http://jsfiddle.net/9WbaC/3/

Another solution is to hard-code the widths inline on the server side with percentages (or `px` if you know the total width in pixels), based on how many top level items there are.